# Alternatives for pHash (media fingerprinting)

Tags: linux, image-processing, image-recognition, content-filtering

I have been using pHash (phash.org) for many years to detect copyright infringements on images and videos. pHash creates fingerprints of media files that can be saved and compared afterwards.

Unfortunately pHash is dead since 2013 and it's hard to get it to work on newer systems.

I'm looking for similar software that allows me to create fingerprints from media files and check for similarity.

I'm looking for software that runs on my own servers and not on third parties (like amazon).